# Significance of 'b' in fopen

Tags: c, file, file-io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what’s the differences between r and rb in fopen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174889/whats-the-differences-between-r-and-rb-in-fopen)

I was designing a **zip-unzip** utility in **C**. The zipping and unzipping worked well if the input files were **.c** or **.txt** files. But if I gave any other file as input it did not unzip. I added the **b** flag when reading and writing files. Since then it has worked perfectly. What is the significance of **b**? I know that it is for binary read/write. Can someone please share the details of what happens at system level? I am working on Linux.

Comment: The "b" flag is guaranteed to make no difference on Linux. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html: "The character `'b'` shall have no effect, but is allowed for ISO C standard conformance".

Comment: No difference on Linux and any other POSIX compliant system, to be precise.

Comment: @Steve Jessop, yes - but that doesn't mean you should omit it if you're working with binary files. Other systems (esp. Windows) still respect it.

Comment: Exactly. I did not add the flag and my utility could not unzip **mp3** or **pdf** files.

Comment: @Roddy: Yes mate I know. I am looking for a better and more elaborate answer.

Comment: @Roddy: true, but it means that the presence or not of `b` cannot explain the different behavior that the questioner observed on Linux, "did not unzip" vs "worked perfectly".