# Ansi C read from PPM file freez

Tags: c, ppm

I am struggling with some issue in my ansi c code. I want to read PPM picture (P6) and then write it to the color (int) arrays. Everything should work great, but unfortunatelly it isn't.

The problem is, that the reading freezes at some point - at this same point each time.

This is a code for reading:

```
int **red,**blue,**green;
    //... Some code, allocations etc.
    static unsigned char a[3];
    for(i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
           for(j = 0; j < y; j++)
           {
                fread(a, 1, 3, pic);
                red[i][j] = a[0];
                //green[i][j] = a[1];
                //blue[i][j] = a[2];
           }
    }
```

When it reads value 24 it is getting crazy - before everything is ok. This value is asigned to the red and it is 24 till the end of loops.

I have noo idea, what is going on there, so this is why I am asking you guys, for some advice - what can be wrong here and how it can be fixed?

**EDIT**

This is my allocation:

```
red = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int*) * x);
green = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int*) * x);
blue = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int*) * x);

for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
       red[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * y);
       green[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * y);
       blue[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * y);
}
```

**EDIT2:**

X is 473 an Y is 600

**EDIT3:**

I did as told and uploaded picture (different this time) with my source code on dropbox: [code](https://db.tt/BrjfqC0r). Despite different picture still it freez at some point. This time it is 70.

Comment: `int **read` or `int **red`?

Comment: how have you allocated red, blue and green.

Comment: Your loop variables are backwards. The outer loop should count from 0 to Y and the inner loop should count from 0 to X.

Comment: @cup I've edited it to show. Thank you for reminding.

Comment: @BitBank Why should i do it backwards? Then it is wrong with my allocation.

Comment: PPM files (and most any image file) are stored in row major order. Your code assumes that the file is stored in column major order (unless your X variable is the height and Y is the width). Also, allocating a separate block for each line is inefficient and unnecessary. Allocate a single block for the 2 dimensional array. Also, reading the file 3 bytes at a time will cause poor performance. Read at least a line at a time if you care about the speed.

Comment: @BitBank Well, that is a point, but this is reading correctly - that is width and height. The stop is way before and of any of values, s I don't think it has anything to do with it.

Comment: @BitBank is right, but those issues don't explain the problem you're seeing. What are the values of X/Y, and can you post a SCCCE? http://sscce.org/

Comment: @Roddy Added as asked.

Comment: You're not opening the file in binary mode : "rb". Note that fixing  this might mean your fscanfs need tweaking.

Comment: @Roddy That was it. It came out also, that fscanf is working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you linked to, you're not opening the file in binary mode : `"rb"`.

See : [what's the differences between r and rb in fopen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174889/whats-the-differences-between-r-and-rb-in-fopen)

Note that fixing this might mean your `fscanf`s need tweaking.