# Why am I getting trailing garbage data while reading a file

Tags: c, file, text

When reading a file, I am given garbage data from my program, such as ���! at the end of the string. Why is this happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *
read_kernel(char *filename)
{   // Reads a kernel into a string in memory
    char *text = NULL;
    int length;
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

    // Return null if the kernel fails to load
    if (file == NULL)
    return NULL;

    // Find the file size
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    length = ftell(file);
    rewind(file);

    //text = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * length);
    text = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (length + 1));
    if (text == NULL)
        return NULL;

    // read the file's text into the text buffer
    fread(text, length, 1, file);
    fclose(file);
    file = NULL;

    text[length] = '\0'; // added zero terminator
    return text;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot the NUL byte at the end of the string.  Allocate `length + 1` bytes then set `text[length] = '\0';`.

Comment: probably because it is not zero terminated

Comment: Yep, it needed to be zero terminated. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Watch out with "r" as an argument to `fopen`. You state you are reading "text", but then you use `ftell` and `fread`. For safety, use "rb". See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174889/whats-the-differences-between-r-and-rb-in-fopen

Comment: @Jongware Good point, but you might want to also mention that this really only matters on Windows platforms\*. In Linux (and presumably Mac as well), "rb", "rt", and "r" are all identical, and the "t" and "b" flags are supported only for code compatibility with Windows.  \*(and perhaps some other relatively obscure platforms that use multi-character line endings, although I can't name any off the top of my head)

Comment: @MikeHolt: thanks for those comments. I've been switching between Mac and Windows programming for so long, I've developed my own way of dealing with about every possible permutation of line endings: an `\n` *possibly* followed by an `\r`, and the other way around, constitutes a single line end. Works even in mixed-mode files.