# fwrite creates an output file that is bigger than the input file

Tags: c, binaryfiles, fwrite

I want to read a file bytewise into an array and then write the data of the array reversed
in a new file (program takes filename over command line argument). Tried it with an txt-file
and it worked, but if I try it on a jpg-file the new file is bigger than the original!
The determined file size saved in **long size;** is also correct for jpg-files and write loop
get size-time executed writing one char (char is one byte big, I am right?).
Does anybody know how the output file can get bigger than size*byte?

It doesn't seem logical to me!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{

 FILE *file;
 char *buffer;
 long size;
 char filename[32];

 if(argc>1)
 {
  //determine file size
  file=fopen(argv[1],"r");
  fseek(file,0,SEEK_END);
  size=ftell(file);
  rewind(file);
  if(size>33554432) //32MB
  {
   fclose(file);
   return 0;
  }

  //create buffer and read file content
  buffer=malloc(33554432);
  fread(buffer,1,size,file);
  fclose(file);

  //create new file name and write new file
  strcpy(filename,argv[1]);
  strcat(filename,"_");
  file=fopen(filename,"w");
  {
   long i;
   for(i=size-1;i>=0;i--)
   {
    fputc(buffer[i],file);
   }
  }
  fclose(file);
  free(buffer);

 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could not reproduce (Linux, 64-bit, with gcc). What OS and compiler are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what's the differences between r and rb in fopen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174889/whats-the-differences-between-r-and-rb-in-fopen)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comments you're receiving are implying something: the newline character `\n` works differently in text mode on Windows compared with some other systems.

`fputc('\n', file)` on Windows actually writes two bytes if `file` was opened in text mode "w", as if you did `fwrite("\r\n", 1, 2, file)`. This means for any `\n` byte read by `fread`, you're writing two bytes back.

If you want to write binary data back, you need to open your output file using the mode `"wb"` to `fopen()`. You also need to open it for reading in binary mode, `"rb"`.