# C - Reading entire file come with garbage at the end

Tags: c, file

So im trying to read an entire text file using this function:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(path, "r");
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
int tamanioArchivo = sizeof(char) * ftell(fp);
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
char* archivo = malloc(tamanioArchivo + 1);
fread(archivo, tamanioArchivo + 1, 1, fp);
//do something with archivo
fclose(fp);
free(archivo);
```

I debugged it and the problem seems to be on the `fread` line. It brings back the file and adds some garbage at the end. Any ideas what im doing wrong?

Comment: You read one byte to many. And you never terminate the string.

Comment: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/FIO19-C.+Do+not+use+fseek%28%29+and+ftell%28%29+to+compute+the+size+of+a+regular+file

Comment: @xing Thanks for the answer but sadly already tried it and fail.

Comment: and In such a case, the correct file size may not be obtained.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thats because text files ends in '/0'. But anyway i also tried and failed without the +1.

Comment: No, text files do *not* automatically end in that. Unless *explicitly written!*

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I tried with a small file (30 characters) and count them manually. And the size was right.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Really? OK. Im going to test a little more. Dont leave me. lol

Comment: @Marco The C standard does not guarantee it.

Comment: The problem is with the code that was commented out. Please provide an actual [mcve].

Comment: @AnttiHaapala The problem is that is quite complex im sending it through sockets and stuff. If the problem persits i will isolate it and upload a real example.

Comment: notes 268) _fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END), has
**undefined behavior** for a binary stream_

Comment: Given `fread(archivo, tamanioArchivo+1, 1, fp);`, you have no idea if you read the entire file or not.  You don't check the return value.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude reading one byte too many is true (UV), but does not cause the garbage at the end.  The `fread()` will simply stop reading before `tamanioArchivo+1` characters.  Code lacks knowing where the "end" is as the return value of `fread()` is not used.

Comment: @chux The "garbage" comes from not terminating the array as a string. Which I mentioned.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes because i have some code in between fread and free. And that let me see what value takes 'Archivo' in the next instruction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally C [doesn't care](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174889/whats-the-differences-between-r-and-rb-in-fopen) what the contents of a file are. Whether it's text or binary data, it's read the same way. Meaning if you want to read a string and get something nicely null-terminated, you need to handle that yourself.

```
fread(archivo, tamanioArchivo+1, 1, fp);
```

This reads one extra byte (again, null-termination is a C thing, the file system does not enforce this). Get rid of the plus 1. Then you must ensure that it's null-terminated:

```
archivo[tamanioArchivo] = '\0';
```

Comment: Note that you must still _allocate_ one extra byte; that is, the `malloc` call is correct in the original code.

Comment: And how do you know if the `fread()` call worked?  You're not checking the return value.

Comment: Likewise for `fopen` and `malloc`, but I was just addressing the original question.

Comment: Im using the eclipse debugger that gives me on every instruction the value of return. @AndrewHenle

Comment: @Marco Good to hear. Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @Max Yes! but i ended up implementing an mmap.

Comment: @Marco, It's nice that your debugger gives you the return values, but you should be checking those values in your code, not just looking at them in the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

The "garbage" comes from improperly examining/printing `archivo` and code not noting how much was read.

`fread()` saves into  `archivo` data, but that data is not certainly *null character* terminated - a C *string*.  **Append a `'\0'`** if `archivo` is to point to a  *string*.

But where? **After the last character read** - which is determined by the return value of `fread()`, **not after the number of characters requested**.

Even without an error, the return value may be less than the number of requested characters due to text mode end-of-line translation of `"\r\n"` into `"\n"`.  The value returned from `ftell()` is not necessarily the numbers of characters that will be read in text mode.

No need to attempt to read `tamanioArchivo+1` characters.  Use `tamanioArchivo`.

Also see [@ Andrew Henle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46240194/c-reading-entire-file-come-with-garbage-at-the-end/46242622?noredirect=1#comment79453601_46242622) good comment about `fread(ptr, element_size, number_of_elements, stream)` parameter order.

```
// Note that the file is opened in text mode, not binary mode
FILE *fp = fopen (path, "r");

fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
// int tamanioArchivo = sizeof(char) * ftell(fp);
long tamanioArchivo = ftell(fp);
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET); // or `rewind(fp);

// Good to allocate +1 for the null chracter
char* archivo = malloc(tamanioArchivo + 1u);

// Save the return value and drop the +1
// fread(archivo, tamanioArchivo+1, 1, fp);
size_t read_count = fread(archivo, 1, tamanioArchivo, fp);

// bad
// bytes read may be less than the offset due to CR/LF-->LF or input error
archivo[tamanioArchivo] = '\0';

// good
archivo[read_count] = '\0';

//do something with archivo
puts(archivo); 

fclose (fp);
free(archivo);
```

---

Robust code would check the return value of `fopen()`, `malloc()`, `fseek()`, `ftell()` for unusual return values.  The seek to the end, `ftell()` method for determining file length has additional limitations.  Alternatives depend on various unposted coding goals.

Comment: `size_t read_count = fread(archivo, tamanioArchivo, 1, fp);`?  Isn't that backwards? See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fread.html You're asking `fread()` to read *one* item of size `tamanioArchivo` bytes, and since `fread()` returns the number of *items* successfully read, you'd get a return value of `1` on success.  I'd think you want `size_t read_count = fread(archivo, 1, tamanioArchivo, fp);` for the return value to be a count of the number of bytes actually read.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes.  Code amended.

Answer (score 1):

Try this example:

```
/* Open Fpga config file */
fpconf = fopen(file, "rb");
if (fpconf == NULL) {
     return ERROR;
}

/* set SEEK_END to read the file size using ftell */
fseek(fpconf, 0L, SEEK_END);

bsize = ftell(fpconf);
print_dbg("Size of file: %d bytes\n", (int)bsize);

/* set file offset 0 */
fseek(fpconf, 0L, SEEK_SET);

data = (uint8_t *) malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * bsize);
if (data == NULL) {
    print_err("Error in malloc\n");
    return ERROR;
}

/* Read data from file and store into buffer */
fread(data, bsize, 1, fpconf);

/* Close file */
fclose(fpconf);
```

Comment: `sizeof(uint8_t)` is 1 _by definition_, just like `sizeof(char)`; you should never write it.

Comment: yes. It is not required.

Comment: The problem is the missing null terminator at the end of the file contents read into memory. You must allocated one extra byte and set the null terminator after the bytes read from the file.