# Copy text file into char* array

Tags: c, arrays, file, io

```
FILE *fp;
char *f_array[256];
int f_length;
int *a = 0;

fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
f_length = ftell(fp);
printf("%d\n\n", f_length);
int n = 1, i = 0;
while (n > 0)
{
    n = fscanf(fp, "%s", f_array[i]);
    i++;
}
```

I am trying to copy the contents of a .txt file into a char* array. Much like what would happen with InternetReadFile and lpbuffer. However, I cannot seem to get this right. I need my array to be filled with the contents of the .txt file character by character. Any suggestions?
I need the array to be single-dimensional

Comment: Don't use fscanf for this, use fread.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading the whole text file into a char array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747086/reading-the-whole-text-file-into-a-char-array-in-c)

Comment: @I'L'I I checked out the linked post and am now receiving the "entire read fails" error

Comment: No worries, thought it might be of use — glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calculating the length of the file but you don't use this information in
any way.

```
char *f_array[256];
```

This is an array of dimension 256 of pointers to `char`. `f_array[i]` is
uninitialized and it's pointing into the digital nirvana, passing it to
`fscanf` yields undefined behaviour. You would need to declare it as something
like this:

```
char f_array[255][255];
```

But then you are limiting yourself to max 255 strings, you are not storing it
into a single string. Also you are storing max. 255 words. Use `fgets` or
`fread` to get the whole content at once.

```
char file[f_length + 1];

rewind(fp);

fread(file, f_length, 1, fp);

file[f_length] = 0; // terminate the string

printf("Whole file is: %s\n", file);
```

Here you are storing the whole file in an array of `char`s. Also after setting
the file at the end, you'll need to rewind the file to the beginning, otherwise
you are not reading anything.

Comment: This code is not reliable.  `fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");` opens the file in text mode.  But `ftell()` on a stream in text mode does not return the number of bytes in the file, or even the number of bytes that can be read from the file.  Per [**7.21.9.4  The `ftell` function**, paragraph 2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.4p2) of [the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

Comment: (cont)  "For a text stream, its file position indicator contains unspecified
information, usable by the
`fseek`
function for returning the file position indicator for the
stream  to  its  position  at  the  time  of  the
`ftell`
call;  the  difference  between  two  such
return values is **not necessarily a meaningful measure of the number of characters written read**"  For example, on Windows `file[f_length] = 0; // terminate the string` will not properly terminate the string.

Comment: @AndrewHenle this is new to me, I've read the `ftell` man page on my system at work (debian 8) and the page does not mention this at all. I've been doing this on linux for years without a problem. In fact  in Linux `b` is ignored (my man page even says *all POSIX conforming systems*) . To be portable, what would you suggest, `fopen("test.txt", "rb");`?

Comment: @Pablo It works on Linux because Linux is (mostly) POSIX-compliant, and [POSIX defines `ftell()` to return a byte offset](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ftell.html):  "`ftell()` ... shall return the current value of the file-position indicator for the stream measured in bytes from the beginning of the file."  But there's [a portability problem with `fseek()` on a binary stream](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.2p3):  "A binary stream need not meaningfully support `fseek` calls with a whence value of `SEEK_END`."

Comment: @Pablo (cont)  [Additionally](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note268):  "Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END)`, has **undefined behavior for a binary stream** ..."  So, there is no *portable* way that's strictly compliant with the C standard to get the size of a file other than to read it `char`-by-`char` and count them.  There are some downright *strange* storage systems out there...

Comment: @AndrewHenle Oh I see, I was also reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076043/1480131) which basically says the same. So the only portable way of knowing how long you text file is, is by reading the whole file and count the characters yourself? Does that also mean that POSIX's `ftell` contradicts/behaves differently from the standard?

Comment: @Pablo POSIX specifies byte offsets for `fseek()` and `ftell()`, *and* [POSIX `fopen()` states](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html): "The character `'b'` shall have no effect ...`.  So POSIX streams are pure bytes with no character translation.  Windows also specifies bytes *but* translates between `"\n"` in memory and `"\r\n"` on disk, which throws the byte counts off for streams not opened in binary mode.  So, yes, the only portable way to measure the size of file is to count bytes. But technically, you're just counting the number of bytes you can read.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is mainly to do with your data types.  You want to store the file in memory.  That would be a character (byte) array, but you have created an "array of pointers":

```
char *f_array[256];
```

When you probably wanted just:

```
char f_array[256];
```

Then, to do as you asked and read *character by character* into that array, use `fgetc`.  Note that `fgetc` will be far less efficient that just reading the whole file in a single function call with `fread`.  The kernel:

```
while ( EOF != (c = fgetc( fp )) && ++i < MAX_LEN )
    f_array[ i ] = c;
```

In context of a working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ( ) {
    const size_t MAX_LEN = 255;
    FILE * fp;
    char f_array[ MAX_LEN +1];
    int c;
    size_t i = -1;
    f_array[ MAX_LEN +1] = 0;

    fp = fopen("test.txt","r");

    if ( NULL == fp )
        perror("Error opening file");
    else {
        while ( EOF != (c = fgetc( fp )) && ++i < MAX_LEN )
            f_array[ i ] = c;

        fclose (fp);
    }
    f_array[ i ] = 0;
    printf("%zu bytes read\n\n", i);
    printf("Content read:\n%s\n", f_array);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When explaining, please don't call it *"array of arrays"*, that's not an array of arrays, it's an array of pointers. That is huge difference. Calling it array of arrays is misleading. And the cast `(char) c` is unnecessary.

Comment: @Pablo "array of arrays": fair.  I wasn't focused on that particular detail, but the detail that his datatype wasn't fit for purpose.  Mea culpa.  Meanwhile, while answering, you beat me to it, so I'm inclined to just delete my answer.

Comment: don't delete the answer, it's a good answer. Someone might find yours more understandable than mine. Just update the bit with the "array of arrays".

Comment: @Pablo `(char) c` not necessary: That would be stale thinking as I was typing that up.  The compiler would throw a warning if not there.  But the real issue is that `int c` should be `char c`.  Fixed.

Comment: No no, `c` should definitely be `int`, otherwise you will get problems when comparing with  `EOF`.  And I don't get any a warning with `char c = 10;` although 10 is an integer. That's not a problem.

Comment: Huh, different compilers?  I definitely don't get a warning with `char c`, and do get a warning if `int c` and no cast.  GCC 5.4.0, `gcc -o test -Wall test.c`

Comment: I'm using GCC 6.4.0, also with `-Wall`.

Comment: Then newer is better, I suppose.  You win.